# VBA/Macro to find date, copy date and paste

Tags: excel, vba

I’m trying to create a rolling report that provides a daily report, pulls the data from the daily report into a yearly report, and then to a phone-friendly sheet (all in the same workbook),

The daily report is on the first sheet named "Test1".  Cell A1 contains the date applicable for the data.  The range A2:A11 contains the data that I need to copy to the second sheet, named "Test2".  In Test2, I have all the days of the year across the columns C5:HD5.

What I would a macro to do:

- search for Test1 A1's daily date in the range in Test2
- copy Test1's A2:A11 data to Test2 under the corresponding found date (for instance, to C6:C15)
- pull the same data from Test1 and copy it into the “Dashboard” sheet (a Blackberry-friendly format). This sheet organizes data by day-of-week, so 2014-08-20 would be pasted to WED
- overwrite any existing data
- if date not found, produce an error

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks for your help Tony ! Its still going to the wrong day. i have a file for today (19th, Tuesday (K8:J13)) its pasting the data to WED column (K8:K13) if i change the date to the 21st, (THU (L8:L13) it paste the data to SAT(N8:N13)

I dont have any hidden columns or rows. ive checked the date formats all seem to be good.

Cheers.

THINK I CRACKED IT!! WHOOP WHOOP, My region settings were set to US, and the start of the week was set to Monday. corrected those, and it seems to be working !

thanks heaps !!

Comment: I find your question a bit confusing (specially the part where you want to _phone_ a spreadsheet :). Can you provide the code you have so far?

Comment: @milz, he's missing a hyphen... should be phone-friendly. nigel, please explain the format of the "dashboard sheet" a little better.  Does it contain only 7 days?  What's its layout?

Comment: All the days of the year go from C5 to NC5 if it's not a leap year. HD5 is only up to 2014-07-29.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Really appreciate it! Sorry about the confusion on the phone-friendly bit. But yes the 1st design was correct. Thanks again!

Comment: Hello, ive run into a little problem. im using the 2nd vba below. Problem is when its pasting the date to the dashboard. its not pasting in the correct day. As per the 1st diagram below the days of the week start from H7 (sunday), through to N7 (saturday) howerver if i paste a file for Monday (18th), it goes in Tuesday. if i paste a file for Wendesday (20th) it goes to friday... I really appreciate the help! thanks !!

Comment: Your target location's off. Replace the paste to Dashboard with this: `Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("G8").Offset(, Weekday(dDate)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

Comment: Cheers, its still pasting to the wrong day.

Comment: The `Weekday(dDate)` function returns a value from 1 to 7. Because it's not generating the proper offset, maybe your OS's regional settings are interfering. What country are you in? On the Test1 sheet, temporarily enter the formula `=text(A1,"ddd")` in a cell near your A1 date. See if it appears as the day you think it should be. I'm a big proponent of the international date format YYYY-MM-DD as defined in the [ISO 8601 standard](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/iso8601.htm), so there's never any confusion.  You might want to change your A1 cell's format to reflect this standard.

Comment: It shouldn't matter, but you could also try changing `Weekday(dDate)` to `Weekday(dDate,1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments, the Dashboard sheet is formatted as follows:

```
    +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
    |     |  H  |  I  |  J  |  K  |  L  |  M  |  N  |  O  |          
    +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
    |  7  | Sun | Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat |     |
    +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
    |  8  |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
    +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
    |  9  |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
    +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

... this should work:

```
Sub Roller()
   Set dDate = Worksheets("Test1").Range("A1")
   Set rCell = Worksheets("Test2").Range("C5:NC5").Find(What:=dDate, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
   If rCell Is Nothing Then
      MsgBox "Date " & dDate & " not found in Test2"
   Else
      ' Copy Test1 data
      Worksheets("Test1").Range("A2:A11").Copy
      ' Paste to Test2
      rCell.Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
      ' Paste to Dashboard
      Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("G8").Offset(, Weekday(dDate)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
      MsgBox "Data copied"
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Dunno why this got downvoted... I answered the dude's question.